# Leftside Treeview and rightside it's relevant content div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hi can any one please help me how to show a Treeview in the Leftside and it's relevant content in the right side.

I have downloaded the Treeview structure from this site: http://www.destroydrop.com/javascripts/tree/

```
d = new dTree('d'); d.add(0,-1,'StratApps');
d.add(1,0,'First Folder','page1.html')
d.add(2,1,'Packages','page2.html');
d.add(3,2,'Pkg_Load_Dim','page3.html');
d.add(4,2,'Pkg_Write_to_File','#');
d.add(5,1,'Interfaces','#');
d.add(6,5,'Int_Load_Order_Dim','#');
d.add(7,5,'Int_Load_Channel_Dim','#');
d.add(8,1,'Procedures','#');
d.add(9,8,'Proc_Update_Order','#');
d.add(10,8,'Proc_Process_Errors','#');
document.write(d);
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but here's a non-JavaScript treeview you might want to consider using. http://www.thecssninja.com/css/css-tree-menu

Comment: from where is the relevant content coming? is it already loaded an hidden in the document?or it is coming from a url?

Comment: yes it is hidden in Divs like ("display : none") in the same page. The left-side Treeview is working fine with the downloaded script. The left side code is in this way:

Comment: d = new dTree('d');
  d.add(0,-1,'StratApps');
  //d.add(1,0,'First Folder','javascript:alert("hi")');
  d.add(1,0,'First Folder','page1.html')
    
  d.add(2,1,'Packages','page2.html');
  d.add(3,2,'Pkg_Load_Dim','page3.html');
  d.add(4,2,'Pkg_Write_to_File','#');
  
  d.add(5,1,'Interfaces','#');
  d.add(6,5,'Int_Load_Order_Dim','#');
  d.add(7,5,'Int_Load_Channel_Dim','#');
  
  d.add(8,1,'Procedures','#');
  d.add(9,8,'Proc_Update_Order','#');
  d.add(10,8,'Proc_Process_Errors','#');
  document.write(d);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

include

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

add

```
<div class="content"></div>
```

and

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('a').click(function(e){
           e.preventDefault();
           $(".content").text($(this).attr('id'));
// you can write the code here to populate your required content area eg:div, span, p
        })
    })
    </script>
```

This will load the id of the clicked 'a' to the div with class content

EDIT: work a relation between content and the matching 'a' tag